# C# skipping or ignoring empty boxes in a loop not working

Tags: c#

Playing with some code and I am not sure why my foreach is failing. The idea is simply to skip empty textboxes (not add to list). What I am failing to figure out is why the continue is applying to all the textboxes in the loop and not just the specific ones in the if statement:

```cs
foreach (var child in children)
            {
                if (child.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox3.Text)) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox7.Text)))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    UserText.Add(((TextBox)child).Text);
                }
             }
```

This is probably a trivial thing I am overlooking.

Comment: because you're testing the specified textboxes - but you're using the result of the test for all the textboxes.

Comment: You're applying the logic to **all** children based on the same 2 TextBoxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner `if` condition always yields same result regardless of current iteration object(textbox). It probably evaluates to `true` every iteration and hence your loop `continue`s. What you need to do for your purpose is to check if `child` textbox is empty or not. Please replace your if condition

```
if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox3.Text)) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox7.Text)))
{
   continue;
}
```

with:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty((TextBox)child.Text))
   continue;
```